# How select the max date for the user column by column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to get the maximum date for userId and group by userId

I don't now how it do :c
My table:

```
Id: 1    userId:1        activitydate:2019-02-15 08:03:11
Id: 2    userId:1        activitydate:0001-01-01 00:00:00
Id: 3    userId:2        activitydate:2019-02-15 07:38:30
Id: 4    userId:2        activitydate:2019-02-15 06:30:30
Id: 5    userId:3        activitydate:2019-03-01 09:17:04



select userid,maxvalue(activitydate)
from wearabledata
group by userid
```

Actual Result:

My table:

```
Id: 1    userId:1        activitydate:2019-02-15 08:03:11
Id: 3    userId:2        activitydate:2019-02-15 07:38:30
Id: 5    userId:3        activitydate:2019-03-01 09:17:04
```

Comment: try `max` instead of `maxvalue`

Comment: @michaeak omg, thank you :)
can you add in answer your comment)

Comment: You are welcome -- others proposed this solution, no need to put the same solution again, if you want to give a thumb up there are ways for it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DISTINCT ON keyword is exactly you need for you solution :

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (userid)
       userid,activitydate
FROM   wearabledata
ORDER  BY userid, activitydate DESC;
```

Comment: That is the coolest way. And you can be sure it will help you later in very critic times.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  userId,
  max(activitydate) as maxvalue
FROM
  wearabledata
GROUP BY
  userId;
```